# How to move node contents from local to server environments?

Tags: nodes, migrations

What is the best way to move node contents from a local environment to a server environment?

I don't want to go with the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) modules.

Any examples that we can go with dbscripts?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using module [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate). From the modules project page:

> Back up and restore your Drupal MySQL database, code, and files or migrate a site between environments. Backup and Migrate supports gzip, bzip and zip compression as well as automatic scheduled backups.
>
> With Backup and Migrate you can dump some or all of your database tables to a file download or save to a file on the server or offsite, and to restore from an uploaded or previously saved database dump. You can choose which tables and what data to backup and cache data is excluded by default.